# What is the eccentricity of $4\sqrt{5}x^2 − 17x + y + \frac{1}{8} = 0$?

Tags: conic-sections, factoring

Question: What is the eccentricity of $4\sqrt{5}x^2 − 17x + y + \frac{1}{8} = 0$?

Source: James S. Rickards Invitational (Algebra II Individual)

I know how to calculate eccentricity, but I am having trouble on factoring it in to $\frac{x^2}{a^2}+\frac{y^2}{b^2}=1$ form.

This is what I did: 
$4\sqrt{5}x^2 − 17x + y + \frac{1}{8} = 0$

$4\sqrt{5}x^2 − 17x + y=-\frac{1}{8}$

$4\sqrt{5}(x^2-\frac{17x}{4\sqrt{5}})+1(y+0)= -\frac{1}{8}$

$(x-\frac{17\sqrt{5}}{40})^2+\frac{y}{4\sqrt5}=\frac{-32\sqrt5}{5120}-\frac{289}{160}$

...

Comment: The graph of your equation is a parabola, not an ellipse.

Answer (score 2):

Note, as given, you have: $4\sqrt{5}x^2-17x+y+\frac{1}{8}=0$.

Just rewrite this as $y=-4\sqrt{5}x^2+17x-\frac{1}{8}$.

It is very easy to see now that this is just the equation of a parabola.

Now by definition, any parabola has an eccentricity of $1$.

No need to complete the square here.